# Google DFP ads Image not loading

Tags: adsense, google-dfp

The issue I am running into is rather simple, the creative URL's are not clicking through within certain email clients (most often Gmail). More specifically, in GMail the creative can sometimes click to a blank page where the redirect URL will just sit idly and for some users, it will redirect to the appropriate URL.

I identified that the creative will not click through if the 'img src' and 'href' URL's are not identical (think /ad & /jump & /adx), furthermore I've identified that Google also prepends their content server location to some URI's (Google Content Server URI's look something like this "https://ci3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/....#") thus this makes the img src completely different...yay! We've looked at adding and removing co=1 / 0 --> this hasn't done anything for us.

We also tried hosting the Ads on our server and clicking the email to go to our domain. But on our domain DFP Ad images are not loading and add the style attribute (style="display:none;") on the image and due to that link also not working and we came across the same issue that if the 'img src' and 'href' URL's are not identical Ads will not work.

Can someone help me here and let me know why display:none is being added on the Ads?

Comment: Seems like an issue with the domain not being on SSL. Just added SSL to the domain and it seems working fine now.